# how to read the contents of a php file using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So let's say I have a `form` tag like so. And I want to print the contents of the file to screen using JavaScript. How do I go about doing that?

```
<form action="/missions/basic/3/index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="file.php" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

What I want is to use the `alert()` function to show the contents of file.php, even though the contents are hidden.

Answer (score 3):

> What I want is to use the alert() function to show the contents of file.php, even though the contents are hidden.

You just **can't**. Don't waste your time :)

If your web server is configured correctly it will never output PHP code even if you could request that from JavaScript.

You can grab and show the **output** of a PHP file on the client but not its **source code** like that, unless there is a mess up or it is by design.

Comment: how to grab the output of a php file?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side programming. When you run, it'll return the **output** of server coding not the **server code**